# Symfony2 folder structure, priorities and order

Tags: php, symfony, structure, organization

I'm coming from the ASP.NET MVC world where my folder structure would be:

```
+ProjectName
    -App_Data (databases, xml's and such data)
    -App_Start (function bundles, routes, etc.)
    -Controllers
        -SampleController.cs
    -Models (though I'd usually call models from other projects)
    -Views
        -Sample
            -index.cshtml
    -Scripts
    web.config
    etc.
```

I'm trying to get into PHP Symfony2, right now. I've read some of the documentation and read a tutorial or two, none of which answer this one question that I keep asking myself.

From my understanding bundles are pieces of the web application that I can utilize in the current project as well as other projects I make. They, as one, fill a certain web application function.

I used the command to generate a bundle:

```
$ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Sample/FooBundle --format=yml
```

and I've got some folders and sub-folders and whatnot, but also a Resource folder, which is what confused me.

So what does the web application read first? How does the controller search for the needed view? Does it first go to

```
src/Sample/FooBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig
```

or does it go to

```
app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig
```

Is it smart to keep the views in bundles, or in the 'global' app folder? I've also noticed configurations are being made inside the bundle (which, I suspect have a higher hierarchy than the app 'global' ones). For instance, bundle `AppBundle` doesn't have its own views and configurations, which made me wonder if it's smart to make views inside bundles in the first place.

If I could get a simple answer, or at least a resource about it that could explain the reason behind all of this, I'd be **very** thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By and large, anything within a Bundle can be overridden by "global" application settings and resources. Probably the most useful resources for understanding this are the cookbook entries [How to Override any Part of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html) and [How to Use Bundle Inheritance to Override Parts of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).

To answer your question of whether to keep views in the bundle or global folder - it all depends on whether the views make sense within the bundle itself. If something is going to be used in multiple bundles (e.g. a layout base template) then that makes more sense in the `app` folder.

In terms of your bundling structure - this has changed since I started with Symfony so I'm not an authority on this. The trend nowadays seems to be that if you can split the functionality into a self contained bundle, do that, otherwise pop it in the `AppBundle` that's by default created by Symfony installer. You might want to have a look at [Best Practices for Reusable Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html) for further info.

It is entirely possible to have multiple application bundles with things like entities and resources stored outside of the bundles, e.g.

```
src/Company
    Bundle/
        ManagerBundle/
        FrontendBundle/
    Entity/
    Event/
```

Whether you do this is entirely up to you - your code, your organisation, beyond a few specific instances, Symfony as a framework won't complain about this.

As for bundle configurations being higher in the "hierarchy" than global - usually no though this is tied in with the DI component. It's a lot to get your head around, but the [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html) "Configuration" section is a great place to start.

Comment: This is exactly an answer I was looking for! I salute you sir!

Comment: I only have to add that I started putting views into ```app/Resources/views```instead of the bundles folders, the way I did it a year ago. And you can remove the bundles views folder but you need to clear the cache manually after.

Comment: The best practices section in general of the Symfony documentation is really nice and worth reading. It gives you some really good advices.

Comment: I'll definitely jump into those!